# VBA: Get Min and Max from range selection while ignoring NA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I do this without actually setting a range in excel? Ideally it'd be stored internally (and temporarily) in VBA just for calculation's sake. Obviously the current code will not work since FormulaArray only applies to range objects.

```
    Dim lower As Double
    lower.FormulaArray = "=RoundDown(Min(If(Not(ISNA(objSelection)), objSelection)), 0)"
    Dim upper As Double
    upper.FormulaArray = "=RoundUp(Max(If(Not(ISNA(objSelection)), objSelection)), 0)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resolve the formulas straight to a double type variable, use the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) to call the [ROUNDDOWN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDDOWN-function-2EC94C73-241F-4B01-8C6F-17E6D7968F53), [ROUNDUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-F8BC9B23-E795-47DB-8703-DB171D0C42A7) and [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) functions directly.

```
Dim lower As Double, upper As Double, objSelection As Range

Set objSelection = Selection

'trim any full row or column selections down to the used range
Set objSelection = Intersect(objSelection.Parent.UsedRange, objSelection)

lower = Application.RoundDown(Application.Aggregate(15, 6, objSelection, 1), 0)
upper = Application.RoundUp(Application.Aggregate(14, 6, objSelection, 1), 0)
Debug.Print lower
Debug.Print upper
```

Comment: Works great (and with non-contiguous ranges). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You would remove the vba part from the quotes and concatenate the strings together with `&`:

```
Dim lower As Double
lower = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=RoundDown(Min(If(ISNUMBER(" & Selection.Address & "), " & Selection.Address & ")), 0)")
Dim upper As Double
upper = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=RoundUp(Max(If(ISNUMBER(" & Selection.Address & "), " & Selection.Address & ")), 0)")
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Invalid qualifier" on lower. Is this because lower isn't a Range object? I thought FormulaArray only works on Range objects?

Comment: My bad, I went off the formula not the declaration.  See edit @rocketman

Comment: that is correct max and min do not work with non contiguous areas.